# Find element based on highest value of inputbox in same table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with three columns.

1. Column 1 has inputboxes.
2. Column 2 contains a "conversion" number which multiplies it's value with the value in the inputbox (column 1)
3. and the result is outputted in column 3.

It would look something like this:

```
5    2   10
1    1    1
2    1    2
3    2    6
```

How can I get column 3's value based on the highest inputbox value in the same row?

My code so far:

**HTML**

```
<table border="1px">
    <tbody id="mbtbody">
      <tr>
          <td><input class="weightinputclass" type="number" value="0"></td>
          <td class="conversionclass">5</td>
          <td class="totals"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input class="weightinputclass" type="number" value="0"></td>
          <td class="conversionclass">1</td>
          <td class="totals"></td></tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input class="weightinputclass" type="number" value="0"></td>
          <td class="conversionclass">1</td>
          <td class="totals"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   var rows = $("#mbtbody").children("tr");
   var total = 0;
     rows.each(function(idx, row) {
       var $row = $(row);
       total += parseInt($row.find('input.weightinputclass').val());
       $("#totalweight").html(total);       
     });
})

$(document).on('input', '.weightinputclass', function () {
   var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
   var weight = $row.find("input.weightinputclass").val();
   var conversion= $row.find(".conversionclass").html();
   $row.find(".totals").text(weight*conversion);
})
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/9fyLqfgr/16/

Comment: I'm unclear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to find the input (column 1) that has the highest value among all the rows, and then find column 3's value for that same row?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes, that is what i'd like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I found:

## Javascript

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   var rows = $("#mbtbody").children("tr");
   var total = 0;
     rows.each(function(idx, row) {
       var $row = $(row);
       total += parseInt($row.find('input.weightinputclass').val());
       $("#totalweight").html(total);       
     });

     var currentMax = 0;
     var currentMaxEl;
     $('.weightinputclass').each(function (idx, element) {
        var elVal = parseInt($(element).val());

        if(elVal > currentMax) {
          currentMax = elVal;
          currentMaxEl = $(element);
        }
     });
     var maxWeight = currentMaxEl.parent().parent().children('.totals').first().html();
     $('#highestinput').html(2000 - maxWeight);
})

$(document).on('input', '.weightinputclass', function () {

var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
var weight = $row.find("input.weightinputclass").val();
var conversion= $row.find(".conversionclass").html();
$row.find(".totals").text(weight*conversion);
});
```

## Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9v6j8qub/2/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Sam.

Comment: @Bruno I fixed the script, I forgot a `parseInt()`

Comment: Much appreciated. I think now that I know the logic, I can try do this with jQuery to keep my code uniform.